# Android does not respect the android:layout_height in xml

Tags: android-layout

I am creating a customer view that extends View and include this view in the layout xml file. However it looks like the system does not respect the height I defined in the layout xml file. (The view is put in a relativeLayout)

The xml file looks like this:

```
<com.example.viewtest.MyView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="140dp"
/>
```

However after I run the app on the phone, this view is always given a larger height value. I searched the Android development guide and I am aware of that system does not always respect the dimensions defined.

However what I am now confused at is that the total drawing in the view is less than 140 height, and when i debug the code, I found the getHeight() and getMeasuredHeight() both returns the larger value, which in my example, is 195.

I searched in stackoverflow and google but I did not get any clues about this? Can anybody help me on this? I appreciate it very much!

Thanks,
Qian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layout_height of 140dp is not exactly going to be 140. dp is Density-independent Pixels so it adjusts based on the density of the device. So 140dp on a high end device will be 280 pixels. In your case, your device density is 195/140 ~ 1.4. So you can't always expect to get 140 pixels as the height.

That being said, you can force them to be same height in terms of pixels but I would suggest against it. This will look weird on different devices.

Hope this clarifies things.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the clarification! In this case, I have to calculate the dimension values in the code then. Thank you!